# Are IVs for Pokémon caught from raid battles the same for everybody?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I did a couple of max raid battles with a friend last night. According to my friend’s analysis, the star rating of the raid battle indicates the number of max IVs; so a 4 star raid will have a minimum of 4 max IVs.

My friend has already completed the story and unlocked the ability to check a Pokémon IVs whereas I have not. After we completed and caught a Pokémon from a 4 star raid, they noted their Pokémon had max IVs in HP, Defense, Special Defense, and Speed.

Since I caught the same Pokémon from the raid, will my Pokémon have the same max IVS, or will the IVs be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing multiple raid battles, I have determined that Pokemon caught from raids are the same for everybody.

A few days ago, I finally finished the story and acquired the IV Check you obtain from the battle tower. My friend and I compared Pokemon recently caught from raids, as well as ones from long before I finished the story. Upon our comparisons, IVs, Nature, Ability, and Moveset were the same for every Pokemon that we both caught.